# rectangle covers visuals making them hidden Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Inside the rectangle I placed slicers.

Clicking on the uncovered part of the rectangle moves it in front of the visualizations making them unavailable to interact with, or hidden.

I "Send to back" rectangle but it didnt help.

[image]

The visuals are on a picture below:

[image]

But if I just hoover mouse on a rectangle area - it covers all visuals:

[image]

Any solution to just always keep re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's pretty annoying. I'd suggest voting for [this idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/14910687-lock-out-selection-of-shapes-and-widgets) and maybe Microsoft will fix this eventually.

Currently, the only workaround I can think of would be to make the colored rectangle part of the page background as an image.

[image]